# Rails4 Custom Rake Task with loaded Concerns on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake-task

I'm new to custom rake tasks.
I'm trying to delete events which creation isn't completed by user

Event has nested model "Banner", which is a Document model sub `(Banner<Document)`, used for uploading banner image.
Banner shares a concerns with other image models (like avatarUploadable and is load in model/banner.rb with

```
include Uploadable
```

Uploading works properly

```
#event.rb
has_one :banner, as: :documentable, class_name: "Banner", dependent: :destroy
```

-

```
#banner.rb
class Hero < Document
include Uploadable
```

-

```
#document.rb
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :documentable, polymorphic: true
```

-

```
#cleanup.rake
namespace :cleanup do
  desc "removes stale and inactive events from the database"
     task events: :environment do
        stale_events = Event.where("DATE(created_at) < DATE(?)", Date.yesterday).where.not(status: 'active')
        stale_events.map(&:destroy)
        puts "TASK FINISHED - UNCOMPLETED EVENTS DELETED!"
    end
  end
```

When I try to run `rake cleanup:events` everything works fine locally.

However, in production environment, `heroku run bundle exec rake cleanup:events`
generates this error message :

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Banner::Uploadable
```

I can't figure out how to solve that. How can I load the concerns properly for rake?
Thank you for your help